# How to combine DataFrame columns of strings into a single column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF with about 50 columns. 5 of them contain strings that I want to combine into a single column, separating the strings with commas but also keeping the spaces within each of the strings. Moreover, some values are missing (NaN). The last requirement would be to remove duplicates if they exist.

So I have something like this in my DF:

| symptom_1 | symptom_2 | symptom_3 | symptom_4 | symptom 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| muscle pain | super headache | diarrhea | Sore throat | Fatigue |
| super rash | ulcera | super headache |  |  |
| diarrhea | super diarrhea |  |  |  |
| something awful | something awful |  |  |  |

And I need something like this:

| symptom_1 | symptom_2 | symptom_3 | symptom_4 | symptom 5 | all_symptoms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| muscle pain | super headache | diarrhea | Sore throat | Fatigue | muscle pain, super headache, diarrhea, Sore throat, Fatigue |
| super rash | ulcera | super headache |  |  | super rash, ulcera, headache |
| diarrhea | super diarrhea |  |  |  | diarrhea, super diarrhea |
| something awful | something awful |  |  |  | something awful |

I wrote the following function and while it merges all the columns it does not respect the spaces within the original strings, which is a must.

```py
def merge_columns_into_one(DataFrame, columns_to_combine, new_col_name, drop_originals = False):
    DataFrame[new_col_name] = DataFrame[columns_to_combine].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)
    return DataFrame
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

edit: when I'm writing this question the second markdown table appears just fine in the preview, but as soon as I post it the table loses it's format. I hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to do. Else I'd appreciate your feedback on how to fix the MD table.

Comment: Can you reformat the output you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying, it looks just fine in the preview but as soon as I post the question it loses the MD table format. Do you have any suggestions or workarounds for this? Perhaps I can post an image?

Comment: Seems that it magically fixed itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) **,** [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) **and** [`rstrip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) method:

```
df['all_symptoms']=df1.fillna('').apply(pd.unique,1).apply(','.join).str.rstrip(',')
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:

| symptom_1 | symptom_2 | symptom_3 | symptom_4 | symptom 5 | all_symptoms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| muscle pain | super headache | diarrhea | Sore throat | Fatigue | muscle pain, super headache, diarrhea, Sore throat, Fatigue |
| super rash | ulcera | super headache |  |  | super rash, ulcera, headache |
| diarrhea | super diarrhea |  |  |  | diarrhea, super diarrhea |
| something awful | something awful |  |  |  | something awful |

Comment: Thank you, it was a really clean and clear one-liner solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas [str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas.Series.str.cat), with some massaging:

```
(df
 .fillna("")
 .assign(all_symptoms = lambda df: df.iloc[:, 0]
                                    .str.cat(df.iloc[:, 1:], 
                                             sep=',')
                                    .str.strip(",")
                                    .str.split(",")
                                    .map(pd.unique)
                                    .str.join(","))
         )

         symptom_1        symptom_2       symptom_3    symptom_4 symptom 5                                       all_symptoms
0      muscle pain   super headache        diarrhea  Sore throat   Fatigue  muscle pain,super headache,diarrhea,Sore throa...
1       super rash           ulcera  super headache                                          super rash,ulcera,super headache
2         diarrhea   super diarrhea                                                                   diarrhea,super diarrhea
3  something awful  something awful                                                                           something awful
```

Alternatively, you could run the string operations within plain python, which is usually faster than pandas string methods (they are wrappers around python's string methods anyways):

```
df = df.fillna("")

_, strings = zip(*df.items())

strings = zip(*strings)

strings = map(pd.unique, strings)

strings = map(",".join, strings)

df['all_symptoms'] = [entry.strip(",") for entry in strings]
```

Comment: any speed improvement is really welcomed. Therefore I tried it with no avail:

```python
columns = ['symptom_1', 'symptom_2', 'symptom_3', 'symptom_4', 'symptom_5']
data[columns].fillna('')
_,strings = zip(*data_3[columns].items())
strings = zip(*strings)
strings = map(pd.unique, strings)
strings = map(",".join, strings)
## debugg print
print(data[columns].info())
##
data['all_symptoms'] = [entry.strip(",") for entry in strings]
```
err:
```console
data['all_symptoms'] = [entry.strip(",") for entry in strings]
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, float found
```

Comment: I don't know why I got the formatting so bad in my previous comment. But I double checked an my columns only contain strings:

print(data[columns].info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   symptom_1  4 non-null      object
 1   symptom_2  4 non-null      object
 2   symptom_3  2 non-null      object
 3   symptom_4  1 non-null      object
 4   symptom_5  1 non-null      object
dtypes: object(5)

Comment: not sure why it is seeing a float; might require more investigation; glad though that you got your challenge resolved with the chosen answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you can get an idea how to work around it:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
     {
       "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
       "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
       "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
       "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
     },
index=[0, 1, 2, 3],)

df1["merged"] = df1["A"]+"," + df1["B"]+","+df1["C"]+","+df1["D"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, apply `lambda` function, then use `set()` to collect all the symptoms ignoring repetitions, finally, use simple list comprehension and then join the list elements with a comma using `join()`.

```
df['all_symptoms'] = df.apply(lambda row: ",".join([x for x in set(row) if x is not None]),1)
```

This will return all the symptoms separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code might help you

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'symptom_1' : ["muscle pain", "super rash", "diarrhea", "something awful"], 
        'symptom_2' : ["super headache", "ulcera", "super diarrhea", "something awful"],
        'symptom_3' :["diarrhea", "super headache"],
        'symptom_4' : ["Sore throat"],
        'symptom_5' :["Fatigue"]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['symptom_1','symptom_2']) 
df1 = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['symptom_3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['symptom_4','symptom_5'])

new = pd.concat([df, df1, df2], axis=1) 

new['symptom_6'] = new['symptom_1']+","+new['symptom_2']+","+new['symptom_3'].fillna('')+","+new['symptom_4'].fillna('')+","+new['symptom_5'].fillna('')

print(new)
```